# SvelteKit develop for full CSR - Client Side Rendeing

Tags: firebase, frontend, sveltekit

I use SvelteKit with Firebase.
Since I don't need server I use static-adapter with `prerender = true` in `svelte.config`. Everything is working good after running build and preview. In dev mode however the server side is running and I get some errors which I don't get while running the build.

Is there a way to run in dev mode as a full CSR without server side support? Not just to avoid the errors but also to be sure I am not developing unintentional server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the root `+layout.ts (or .js)`:

```
export const ssr = false;
```

Reference: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options